# Any tips on staying agile when you are sedentary most of the day?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines

I used to be a lot more agile. But since the past 1 year, I have a job where I am sitting at my desk at home for the better part of the day. I can feel myself getting more "inert", I am moving much slower than before.

Apart from the regular 4-5 days a week exercise schedule, are there any tips for people like me to become more agile and being more active?

Comment: Prolonged sitting is bad for your health.
Try to stand up from your desk and walk a little, say every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Do many quick warm ups through the day. This makes muscles warmer and more elastic and the mind more ready for any challenge.

Stationary things tend to remain stationary, whilst things in motion tend to remain in motion.

This is why it is hard for really active people to become inactive, and it is really hard for inactive people to do basic taks .

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The answer here should be fairly obvious. If you want to be agile, then you need to train for agility. But what does that look like? Explosive movements, sports associated training, and technique specific training (if you want to do flips better, do flips).